# Apache Deny all and authorize IP address with authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

How to deny the access to a page from any IP except from one IP address but have basic authentication for this authorized IP address in Apache? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you examined the order and allow directives in the http://httpd.apache.org web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/some/location/.htaccess

```
Allow from 149.15.90.70
deny from all
AuthType basic
AuthName "My Protected Page"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /staff/widricd/htpasswd
Require user mint
```